# How do I use C# to deserialize raw R Dataframe stored in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, r, dataframe, deserialization

One of our analysts is storing image (png) plots into a SQL server database that have been generated by R scripts using the following:

```
##### save all the plots in database
image_file = tempfile()
png(filename = image_file)
plot(training_plot[[1]])
dev.off();
Plot_Output1 <- data.frame(data = readBin(file(image_file, "rb"), what = raw(), n = 1e6))
Plot_Output1_Serialized <- as.raw(serialize(Plot_Output1, connection = NULL))
```

I am not R expert but from what I can tell, the image is converted to a DataFrame called Plot_Output1 and then that is serialized int some raw format and stored in SQL Server.

As an example the data is stored in SQL Server as a VARBINARY -- example column definition:

```
Column Name  Data Type       Allow Nulls   
ImagePlot  | varbinary(MAX) | [v]
```

Subsequently, I am successfully retrieving the record and attempting to conver it back into a DataFrame

```
    private static BitmapImage test(byte[] imageData)
    {
        MemoryStream binstream = new MemoryStream(imageData);
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        DataFrame df = (DataFrame)bf.Deserialize(binstream);

        var image = new BitmapImage();

        return image;

    }
```

but I am getting the error  **"The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 58-0A-00-00-00-02-00-03-02-02-00-02-03-00-00-00-03 ..."**

So basically, I don't understand how to convert the data back into a DataFrame so that I can retrieve the image portion of the data...any help is appreciated.

Comment: why don´t you use Image datatype? It is SQL Server best implementation to manage images

Comment: @NicoRiff the image datatype has been deprecated in favor of varbinary(max) since sql 2005. I would strongly urge not using the image datatype at all. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx